# print complete line which includes a search word. the eol is a dot not a line feed

Tags: python-3.x

I have a long text (winter's tale). Now I want search for the word 'Luzifer' and than the complete line, which includes the word 'Luzifer' should be printed. With complete line I means all between2 dots.

My scrip is printing 'Luzifer' and all following words til end of line dot. But I want have the full line. 
For example. the text line is:
'Today Luzifer has a bad day. And he is ill'
My scrip is printing: 'Luzifer has a bad day.'
But I need the complete line inclusive today.

Is there a function or way to rad back ?

Here my script:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3.6
 # coding: utf-8

 import re

 def suchen(regAusdruck, textdatei):
     f = open(textdatei, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
     rfctext = f.read()
     f.close()
     return re.findall(regAusdruck, rfctext)

 pattern1 = r'\bLuzifer\b[^.;:!?]{2,}'
 print(suchen(pattern1, "tale.txt"))
```

Comment: Why are you using regex? `with open(...) as f: for line in f: if 'Luzifer' in line: print(line)`.

Comment: behause it was working when I was searching or an string

Comment: @jonrsharpe The regular expression shown in the question tries to limit the result to `Luzifer` as a single word. It would not match if `Luzifer` is part of another word. I know the text or at least parts of it and this actually makes a difference in output. Can't say if it really matters to the OP though.

Comment: Please check out the `splitlines()` method in the python documentation for [string types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) to understand why it is confusing that you refer to a line as being between `'.'` is confusing and resulted in answers that were not what you are looking for.  Rather than trying to change the definition of a line in your question, it would be *much* clearer if you updated the question to state you want to search sentences, not lines.

Comment: @SethMMorton,I have changed the headline and description of my question. I hope now it's better explained what I'm searching for. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most straightforward ways of handling this is to read in your entire text (hopefully it is not too big), split on `'.'`, and then return the strings that contain your search word.  For good measure, I think it will be useful to replace the newline characters with a space so that you don't have any strings broken into multiple lines.

```
def suchen(regAusdruck, textdatei):
    with open(textdatei, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        entire_text = f.read()
        entire_text = entire_text.replace('\n', ' ')  # replace newlines with space
        sentences = entire_text.split('.')
        return [sentence for sentence in sentences if regAusdruck in sentence]
        # Alternatively...
        # return list(filter(lambda x: regAusdruck in x, sentences))

print(suchen('Luzifer', "tale.txt"))
```

If you really need to use a regular expression (which may be the case for more complicated searches) a modification is only needed in the `return` statement.

```
def suchen(regAusdruck, textdatei):
    with open(textdatei, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        entire_text = f.read()
        entire_text = entire_text.replace('\n', ' ')  # replace newlines with space
        sentences = entire_text.split('.')
        # We assume you passed in a compiled regular expression object.
        return [sentence for sentence in sentences if regAusdruck.search(sentence)]
        # Alternatively...
        # return list(filter(regAusdruck.search, sentences))

import re
print(suchen(re.compile(r'\bluzifer\b', flags=re.IGNORECASE), "tale.txt"))
```

Comment: the script are fine, but it printed also lines which doesn't include the search word.

Comment: No, the _lines_ included the search word. Otherwise they would not be in the result.  But your lines may contain more than one sentence. Say a whole paragraph in each line. So this would print all paragraphs containing the word.  Also not just as a single word but also if it's part (prefix, suffix, or embedded) of another word.

Comment: @harvey186 It sounds like you need to clarify whether you only want the *lines*containing the search word or the *sentences* containing the search word. Those are very different things.

Comment: oh, sorry, I what only the line, not the sentence.

Comment: Are you sure this is returning lines that do not include the search word?

Comment: Yes, absolute.  This is from tale.txt: Pearly sucht einen dunklen Abwasserkanal auf. Dort trifft er auf seinen Boss Luzifer, den Richter. Pearly ersucht Luzifer um die Genehmigung, ausnahmsweise Zugang zu einer  ------- and this is the output: ['Pearly sucht einen dunklen Abwasserkanal auf. Dort trifft er auf seinen Boss Luzifer, den Richter. Pearly ersucht Luzifer um die Genehmigung, ausnahmsweise Zu   ---- As you can see, the first line starting with "Pearly" doens't include the search word "Luzifer" and that's not the only line.

Comment: Where are the newline characters in the input?  Python defines a line as text between newline characters.

Comment: @harvey186 I think you need to clarify your definition of line. Be specific. Right now I think we are using two different definitions which is where the confusion is coming from.

Comment: a line is ending with a dot --- this is one line -> Pearly sucht einen dunklen Abwasserkanal auf. This is the next one --> Dort trifft er auf seinen Boss Luzifer, den Richter.

Comment: @SethMMorton  Yes, I think we are talking about different definitions. For me a line is ending with a dot. Because Python uses the new line character for splitting I can't use the rstrip() function.

Comment: @harvey186 When processing text files, a line is universally known as the set of characters between the newline character (that's why it is called the new*line* character in the first place!). Please update your question to state that you want only the sentences containing the keyword, not the line. Sentences are split by periods (`.`). I specifically asked if this is what you wanted previously and you said no.

Comment: @SethMMorton, sorry, I think my "no" was, because of a misunderstanding.

Comment: @SethMMorton: I have just tried you new version. It's great. Many thanks !!

Comment: @harvey186 That's great.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for the appropriate action when someone answers your questions.